# How to combine lines into a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, fill

I want to combine the lines in my object into a shape (or multiple petal shapes) so I can still have the lines and fill the petals with color (or different petals with different colors). How do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. select all lines, as they are in your example;
2. select the Shape Builder tool in the toolbox, hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>;
3. click all areas between your lines to change them into objects.

Now you can colour and change all your objects. If there is any parts you do not want, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> them when using the Shape Builder to remove them.

Comment: How to apply Shape builder tool to line !! As KShiroko Attach image .. object is in stroke.

Comment: @User228 I'm sorry, but your comment doesn't make sense to me. Could you explain what you mean? Thanks!